# Unable to initialize firebase flutter

Tags: flutter

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
    

                  ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.2.0/lib/src/firebase.dart:41:30: Error: Expected ';' after this.
FirebaseAppPlatform app =1 await _delegate.initializeApp(
                         ^
```

../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.2.0/lib/src/firebase.dart:41:30: Error: A value of type 'int' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'FirebaseAppPlatform'.

- 'FirebaseAppPlatform' is from 'package:firebase_core_platform_interface/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-4.0.1/lib/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart').
  FirebaseAppPlatform app =1 await _delegate.initializeApp(
  ^

Restarted application in 382ms.
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.2.0/lib/src/firebase.dart:41:30: Error: Expected ';' after this.
FirebaseAppPlatform app =1 await _delegate.initializeApp(
^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.2.0/lib/src/firebase.dart:41:30: Error: A value of type 'int' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'FirebaseAppPlatform'.

- 'FirebaseAppPlatform' is from 'package:firebase_core_platform_interface/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-4.0.1/lib/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart').
  FirebaseAppPlatform app =1 await _delegate.initializeApp(
  ^

  ^

Comment: Please add some code/

Comment: Is it for Web or Mobile?

Comment: it is for mobile

Comment: have you try flutter clean and then run it again? as the error messages says, it may be related to the firebase libs, try to change the firebase lib version and the do pub get....

Answer (score 0):

Use this to initialize Flutter:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
```